# How to save MATLAB figure in full screen

Tags: matlab, save, figure

I would like to save the figure plot in in FULL SCREEN.

My code save the figure in tiff file but not in full screen; with overlapping txt titles.
please, any one does know how to solve this issue ?

```
scrsz = get(0,'ScreenSize');
set(figure,'position',scrsz);

subplot(2,2,1)

surf(peaks(30))
title(' **********************      test        ************************** '); 

subplot(2,2,2)
surf(peaks(30))
title(' **********************      test        ************************** ');

subplot(2,2,3)
surf(peaks(30))
title(' **********************      test        ************************** '); 

subplot(2,2,4)
surf(peaks(30))
title(' **********************       test       ************************** '); 

saveas(gcf,'test.tiff')
```

answer:

```
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto','PaperPosition',[0 0 20 10])
print -dtiff -r96 itest.tiff
```

Comment: You can use [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102219-how-do-i-make-a-figure-full-screen-programmatically-in-matlab) to make the figure full-screen and then use [`saveas`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html) by using `gcf`.

Comment: I prefer if you have to suggest something to use the above code and not a link!!!! FYI I tried many hours to make it work and I tried your suggest method! it DOES NOT work!  Please, if you have available time, you could try the above code and you could see! any other suggestion ( if you use the above code and you get an output image in full screen without overlapping titles ) is more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the dimensions in paper space and use *"Print"* instead of *"Save as"*.
For example:

```
set (gcf, 'PaperPositionMode', 'manual','PaperPosition',[0 0 30 20])
print -dtif -r 150 test.tiff
```

This will create a `tiff` 30x20 cm with a resolution of 150dpi.
Playing with the dimensions you can easily obtain figures with the size you need.

The attribute "position" is related to `.fig` files and define the position of that files on the screen space. After printing (saving Matlab figures as pictures `jpeg`, `png`, `tiff` or `pdf`) the dimensions should be defined in the paper space.

I hope this can help.

Comment: OK, I play a little but with what you suggest: Eventually, I figure out that what I want was that:

set(gcf,'PaperUnits','inches','PaperPosition',[0 0 1920 942]) %[left bottom width height dimension of my laptop screen]

print -dtiff  -r0 test.tiff

thank you!

PS ( please edit your answer to accept it )

Comment: no it cause Matlab crash ... I do not know why ... :(

Comment: ok it works:


set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto','PaperPosition',[0 0 20 10])
print -dtiff -r96 itest.tiff  
thank you!